# How to play a video when hovering with the cursor using Promoted Links in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user, video, picture, promoted-links

I am trying to create a meet the team page, where each colleague has a profile picture with their name and job title. When you click on the profile photo it brings you to their user page. I have already completed this part using promoted links, photo also is displaying.

However what I'm trying to achieve is when you hover over the profile picture with the cursor it plays a seperate video clip.

I have creating a column in the promoted link form where the second media file sits but there seems to be some clashes when applying both media files are applied. I was hoping this was possible using sharepoint 2013 interface without any CSS or JScript. I've spent the last few hours to try and find the answer to no avail.

Any hope is appreciated, Thank you